# android studio edit basic activity template

Tags: android, android-studio, settings

OK I would like to EDIT the Basic Activity Template from within Android Studio that is my question.

I have used the title of this question to search on SO and Google with results that do not address the question.

I found answers that say look in this folder at android-studio/plugins/android/lib/templates/activities this question on SO is two years old and I do not have the those sub folder under plugins. I do have availabiles.xml fie that is massive.

I know how to use this idea 
Files > Settings > Editor > File and Code Templates > Others TAB once here I am unsure of what to select to do an EDIT or if this is even the correct place to be.

I would rather not build my own template but if this is the simplest process to answer my question a few hints would be appreciated

I am using Android Studio 2.3.3

Comment: "I do not have the those sub folder under plugins" -- AFAIK, you should. I have it, and content in there was updated as recently as March. Scan your hard drive for a directory named `BasicActivity`.

Comment: @CommonsWare OK we are cooking I did something perhaps dumb a long time ago I put Android Studio stuff here C:\Java\astudio\plugins\android\lib\templates\activities\BasicActivity still not real sure I will fire up SublimeText2 and have a go at it

Comment: Note that your changes are quite likely to be overwritten by future updates to Android Studio.

Comment: @CommonsWare so this is the only way to EDIT the file ? It can not be done from with in Android Studio YES I have worried about that when I first started with AS an article said it was easy to find stuff if you did it this way NOT SO TRUE

Comment: AFAIK, there is no official support for creating or modifying Android Studio templates. Hence, there is no need for Android Studio to make it easy to do.